# Capital letters in frameboxes

Tags: framed, fbox, uppercase

I'm trying to insert capital letters into frameboxes. Every time I use the letter Q on its own or in a string of capital letters, the frameboxes gets stretched vertically compared to the other letters' frameboxes. Is there a workaround for this problem or other fonts maybe?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\framebox[35pt]{P} \framebox[35pt]{Q} \framebox[35pt]{R}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use `\strut Q`  `\strut R`

Comment: If this is for decorative purposes, you’d do better to look for a font with framed initials (e.g., Kramer or Typocaps in the `initials` package).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\strut` to reserve a reasonable vertical space.

Or you can use `\smash{WHATQ}` to **ignore** the vertical dimensions of WHATQ.
With smash, then you have to set *manually* the vertical dimensions, for which I recommend \vphantom with a reasonable size template(A): `\vphantom{A}\smash{WHATQ}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\test{\medbreak \f[35pt]{P} \f[35pt]{Q} \f[35pt]{R} }

% I do not implement the optional parameter properly.
\newcommand{\f}[2][???pt]{\framebox[#1]{#2}}
\test original 

\renewcommand{\f}[2][???pt]{\framebox[#1]{\strut #2}}
\test with strut 

\renewcommand{\f}[2][???pt]{\framebox[#1]{\vphantom{A}\smash{#2}}}
\test with smash
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a `parbox` inside the `framebox`. This would be the solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \framebox{\parbox[c][1em]{35pt}{\centering P}}
    \framebox{\parbox[c][1em]{35pt}{\centering Q}}
    \framebox{\parbox[c][1em]{35pt}{\centering R}}
\end{document}
```

This is the syntac of the `parbox` command:

```
 \parbox[position][height][inner-pos]{width}{text}
```

Above is the original result of the question, below is the output of the solution:

[image]